# Rotating stone confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

First tie a stone with a string and fix it on a stick. At rest,the angle between the stick and the stone will be zero. When we start rotating the stone slowly the angle between the stick and the string (or the stone tied to it) becomes 90 degrees (at extreme). Why doesn't the gravitational force pull the stone in downwards direction? Please explain in simple way,I'm just in highschool.

Edit:Why doesn't the gravity pull back the stone?

Answer (score 0):

Rotating parallel to the ground or perpendicular?

Play, now that that's clarified, when the string rotates with the mass at the end, the force on the string, or tension, from the inertia and centripetal acceleration (google uniform rotational motion to see the vectors) is greater than the downward force of gravity. The tendency of the rock is to fly tangentially outward but the tension in the rope allows for rotation.

[Rotating a stone with a string](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62887/rotating-a-stone-with-a-string)

Comment: parallel to the ground perpendicular to the stick